# Subdomain DNS address could not be found in share hosting

Tags: wordpress, apache, laravel

I am using linux share hosting. I have hosted my laravel project in a subdomain **test.example.com** and the main domain installed by WordPress (Not multisite). When I am trying to access my subdomain it shows *test.example.com’s server **DNS address could not be found**.*

My WordPress (In main domain) **htaccess** file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Just do: `ping example.com` and `ping test.example.com` to make sure if both addresses refer to same IP address. seems like You've not configured Your domain to use hosting's Name Servers (NS).

Comment: main domain example.com (WordPress) site is working but subdomain not works.

Comment: You did not understand me. Main domain can work even if I go to my domain panel: godaddy, name.com and etc and define `@` to refer to hostings server address. I'm talking about to check if IP of host behind subdomain is same as main domains host IP.

Comment: can You write in comments the domain name and subdomain name?

Comment: Ping request could not find host test.example.com

Comment: So there are 2 points of failure: 1) domain not properly configured or not using NS of hosting, 2) problem with shared hosting (not with Your code, htaccess file and etc.)

Comment: Your issue is not valid for StackOverflow's rules, Your question is off-topic by several moments. So add me in skype and let's fix it. my skype: `anarjafarov`

Comment: @Akashkhan if you just created your sub domain you have to wait a while for DNS refresh some reason. after few times it will auto valid.

Answer (score 0):

two things to check here
if you've added the sub-domain and made the laravel's `public` directory root directory.

secondly if there's any `.htaccess` files or code parts rather than those you've mentioned